# Can I share my screen using WebRTC without webcam?

Tags: webrtc

Currently, I am making a web that shows my screen to others using webbrtc.

However, it seems like it can't be executed without webcam, so can all participating people share the screen of the monitor without a webcam and microphone?

It is difficult to proceed because there are no questions or posts about sharing screen without a webcam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Just use `getDisplayMedia` only.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r16jvcm0/) that establishes a WebRTC session and just adds a screenshare.

Comment: I wasn't sure because the code that I worked without a webcam failed. I'll try again Thank you.